# Python instalado mas Environment Variables (Variáveis de Ambiente) não contém as informações

Tags: python, windows

Instalei o Python 3.5 e em seu instalador vem com a opção de colocá-lo automaticamente na Environment Tables, mas não funcionou, como eu faço para adicioná-lo para ele poder compilar?

Answer (score 2):

Para você poder instala-lo nesta área do seu Windows você terá de ir em:

```
Painel de Controle > Sistema e Segurança > Sistema > Configurações Avançadas de Sistema
```

Ao clicar nesta parte, você abrirá uma nova tela e terá de clicar em Variáveis de Ambiente ou Environment Variavles, em seguida, você terá de ir na **Variavel Path** e a editará colocando o seguinte:

```
;C:/Caminho/Para/Seu/Python;
C:/Caminho/Para/Seu/Python/scripts/
```

Após feito isso, caso você esteja em um editor, você deve reinicia-lo, ou caso esteja usando o CMD, basta tentar iniciar o comando novamente!

Answer (score -3):

Passei por esse problema também.

**Como solucionei:**

Meu Windows é o 10 64 bits.
Descobri que a página de downloads do  Python te obriga a instalar a versão 32 bits. 
Isso gera inúmeros problemas.

Para baixar o 64 bits:

Abaixo do link de download, há a opção: *"Looking for Python with a different OS? Python for Windows, Linux/UNIX, Mac OS X, Other"*
Clique em Windows e aparecerão diversas opções de download (inclusive versões alpha e beta).

Ide e sê feliz!